# Nonzero-divisor on the associated graded ring at the maximal ideal implies nonzero-divisor on the ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, graded-rings, local-rings

For a Noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak m)$ , let $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak m} (R):= \oplus_{n \ge 0} \mathfrak m^n/\mathfrak m^{n+1}$ be the associated graded ring.

If $x\in \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2 $ is not a zero divisor on $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak m} (R)$ , then is $x$ also not a zero divisor on $R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More general result is true.

Suppose that $x\in R$ is a non zero element in $R$ and assume that the corresponding class $\overline{x}$ in $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ is not a zero divisor. Pick $y \in R\setminus \{0\}$ such that $x\cdot y = 0$. Now 
$$\overline{x}\cdot \overline{y} = 0$$
where $\overline{y}$ is the class of $y$ in $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$. But $\overline{y}$ is nonzero in $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ (because $y\neq 0$ in $R$ and $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathfrak{m}^n = 0$). Hence by contradiction we deduce that $x$ is not a zero divisor in $R$.

Comment: what is $\overline{y}$ exactly

Comment: Since $y$ is non zero, there exists $n$ such that $y\in \mathfrak{m}^n\setminus \mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$. Then $\overline{y} = y\,\mathrm{mod}\,\mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ is an element of $\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$.